# cannot proceed to scraping or crawling

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape data from this https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5196/licensed-practical-nurse/job (a sample page) but to no avail. I don't knw why it keeps telling that FILTERED OFFSITE REQUEST to another website and referer is none. I just wanted to get the job name, ocation and links of it. Anyway, this is my code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from craigslist_sample.items import CraigslistSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "meridian"
    allowed_domains = ["careers-meridianhealth.icims.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com"]



rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(deny = path_deny_base, allow=('\d+'),restrict_xpaths=('*'))
    , callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )


def parse_items(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    titles = hxs.select('//div[2]/h1')

    linker = hxs.select('//div[2]/div[8]/a[1]')

    loc_Con = hxs.select('//div[2]/span/span/span[1]') 
    loc_Reg = hxs.select('//div[2]/span/span/span[2]') 
    loc_Loc = hxs.select('//div[2]/span/span/span[3]') 
    items = []
    for titles in titles:
        item = CraigslistSampleItem()
        #item ["job_id"] = id.select('text()').extract()[0].strip()
        item ["title"] = map(unicode.strip, titles.select('text()').extract()) #ok
        item ["link"] = linker.select('@href').extract() #ok
        item ["info"] = (response.url)
        temp1 = loc_Con.select('text()').extract()
        temp2 = loc_Reg.select('text()').extract()
        temp3 = loc_Loc.select('text()').extract()
        temp1 = temp1[0] if temp1 else ""
        temp2 = temp2[0] if temp2 else ""
        temp3 = temp3[0] if temp3 else ""
        item["code"] = "{0}-{1}-{2}".format(temp1, temp2, temp3)
        items.append(item)
    return(items)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you check your link extractor using scrapy shell, you see that your start URL only has links to websites not under "careers-meridianhealth.icims.com"

```
paul@paul:~/tmp/stackoverflow$ scrapy shell https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com

In [1]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

In [2]: lx = SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=('\d+'),restrict_xpaths=('*'))

In [3]: lx.extract_links(response)
Out[3]: 
[Link(url='https://www.meridianhealth.com/MH/Careers/SearchJobs/index.cfm?JobID=26322652', text=u'NURSE MANAGER ASSISTANT [OPERATING ROOM]', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://www.meridianhealth.com/MH/Careers/SearchJobs/index.cfm?JobID=26119218', text=u'WEB DEVELOPER [CORP COMM & MARKETING]', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://www.meridianhealth.com/MH/Careers/SearchJobs/index.cfm?JobID=30441671', text=u'HR Generalist', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://www.meridianhealth.com/MH/Careers/SearchJobs/index.cfm?JobID=30435857', text=u'OCCUPATIONAL THERAPIST [BHCC REHABILITATION]', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://www.meridianhealth.com/MH/1800DOCTORS.cfm', text=u'1-800-DOCTORS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://kidshealth.org/PageManager.jsp?lic=184&ps=101', text=u"Kids' Health", fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://www.meridianhealth.com/MH/HealthInformation/MeridianTunedin2health.cfm', text=u'Meridian Tunedin2health', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://money.cnn.com/magazines/fortune/best-companies/2013/snapshots/39.html?iid=bc_fl_list', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

In [4]:
```

You can either change your rule, add more domains to `allowed_domains` attribute, or not define `allowed_attribute` at all (so all domains will be crawl, this can mean crawling A LOT of pages)

But if you look closely at the page source, you'll notice that it include an `iframe`, and if you follow the links, you'll find `https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=0&in_iframe=1&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&ss=1` which contains individual job postings:

```
paul@paul:~/tmp/stackoverflow$ scrapy shell https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com

In [1]: sel.xpath('.//iframe/@src')
Out[1]: [<Selector xpath='.//iframe/@src' data=u'https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com'>]

In [2]: sel.xpath('.//iframe/@src').extract()
Out[2]: [u'https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/?in_iframe=1']

In [3]: fetch('https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/?in_iframe=1')
2014-05-21 11:53:14+0200 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs?in_iframe=1> from <GET https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/?in_iframe=1>
2014-05-21 11:53:14+0200 [default] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/intro?in_iframe=1&amp;hashed=0&in_iframe=1> from <GET https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs?in_iframe=1>
2014-05-21 11:53:14+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/intro?in_iframe=1&amp;hashed=0&in_iframe=1> (referer: None)

In [4]: from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

In [5]: lx = SgmlLinkExtractor()

In [6]: lx.extract_links(response)
Out[6]: 
[Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/login?back=intro&hashed=0&in_iframe=1', text=u'submit your resume', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=0&in_iframe=1&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&ss=1', text=u'view all open job positions', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/reminder?hashed=0&in_iframe=1', text=u'Reset Password', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://media.icims.com/training/candidatefaq/faq.html', text=u'Need further assistance?', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.icims.com/platform_help?utm_campaign=platform+help&utm_content=page1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=platform', text=u'Applicant Tracking Software', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

In [7]: fetch('https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=0&in_iframe=1&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&ss=1')
2014-05-21 11:54:24+0200 [default] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=0&in_iframe=1&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&ss=1> (referer: None)

In [8]: lx.extract_links(response)
Out[8]: 
[Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?in_iframe=1&pr=1', text=u'', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5196/licensed-practical-nurse/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'LICENSED PRACTICAL NURSE', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5192/certified-nursing-assistant/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'CERTIFIED NURSING ASSISTANT', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5191/receptionist/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'RECEPTIONIST', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5190/rehabilitation-aide/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'REHABILITATION AIDE', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5188/nurse-supervisor/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'NURSE SUPERVISOR', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5164/lpn/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'LPN', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5161/speech-pathologist-per-diem/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'SPEECH PATHOLOGIST PER DIEM', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5160/social-worker-part-time/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'SOCIAL WORKER PART TIME', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5154/client-care-coordinator-nights/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'CLIENT CARE COORDINATOR NIGHTS', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5153/greeter/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'GREETER', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5152/welcome-ambassador/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'WELCOME AMBASSADOR', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5146/certified-medical-assistant-i/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'CERTIFIED MEDICAL ASSISTANT I', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5142/registered-nurse-full-time/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'REGISTERED NURSE FULL TIME', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5139/part-time-home-health-aide/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'PART TIME HOME HEALTH AIDE', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5136/rehabilitation-tech/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'REHABILITATION TECH', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5127/registered-nurse/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'REGISTERED NURSE', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5123/dietary-aide/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'DIETARY AIDE', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5121/tcu-administrator-%5Btransitional-care-unit%5D/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'TCU ADMINISTRATOR [TRANSITIONAL CARE UNIT]', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5119/mds-coordinator/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'MDS Coordinator', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/5108/per-diem-patient-service-tech/job?in_iframe=1', text=u'Per Diem PATIENT SERVICE TECH', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/intro?in_iframe=1', text=u'Go back to the welcome page', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='https://media.icims.com/training/candidatefaq/faq.html', text=u'Need further assistance?', fragment='', nofollow=False),
 Link(url='http://www.icims.com/platform_help?utm_campaign=platform+help&utm_content=page1&utm_medium=link&utm_source=platform', text=u'Applicant Tracking Software', fragment='', nofollow=False)]

In [9]:
```

You'll have to follow the pagination links to get all the other job postings.

Comment: so how will I be able to extract data from job postings? and i have said that I will need to recursively scraping so that I can have more data extracted from each pages.

Comment: you can try setting `start_urls=["https://careers-meridianhealth.icims.com/jobs/search?hashed=0&in_iframe=1&searchCategory=&searchLocation=&ss=1"]`

Comment: I saw the result that it visited the links but the problem is that the data is inside the iframe